# ng2 AsyncRoute with legacy ng1 component dependencies

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

As you can see in [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/7TQflb?p=preview), below demonstrates my attempt to lazy-load an angular2 route in an ng1/ng2 hybrid application where the lazy-loaded route has an ng1-upgraded dependency (ng2 beta 7, ng1 1.5).

**main.ts:**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {App} from './app';
import {adapter} from './adapter';
angular.module('ng1app', [])
.component('testy', {
  template: `
    <div>{{ctrl.hi}}</div>
  `,
  controller: function () {
    this.hi = 'howdy'
  },
  controllerAs: 'ctrl',
  bindings: {
    hi: '='
  }
})
.directive('myApp', adapter.downgradeNg2Component(App));


adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['ng1app']);
```

**app.ts:**

```
import { Component, provide } from 'angular2/core'
import { adapter } from './adapter'

import {
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT,
  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
  RouteConfig,
  AsyncRoute
} from 'angular2/router'


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
  directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ]
})
@RouteConfig([
  new AsyncRoute({
    path: '/',
    loader:  () => System.import('./src/Home').then(c => c.Home)
    name: 'Home'
  })
])
export class App { }

[
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, { useFactory:  () => App })
].forEach(provider => adapter.addProvider(provider))
```

**home.ts:**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {adapter} from './adapter';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  template: `
    <div>
      hi
      <testy></testy>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [adapter.upgradeNg1Component('testy')]
})
export class Home { }
```

Basically, this is a hybrid angular1/2 app, where before even bootstrapping I've defined an ng1 component in main.ts. When AsyncRoute tries to load home.ts, I get "EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of class0!" out of the UpgradeNg1ComponentAdapter -- seems it can't find the directive object for `testy`.

I'm wondering whether there's a way to get the injector(s) wired up -- but that's assuming that this problem is even about injector confusion, which for me, is not a certainty, as I'm not familiar with the innards of angular2's injection system.

Should this be possible? Or, "shouldn't this be possible?" ;)

(Ideally, I'd be wanting to lazy-load the ng1 components, but first things first would be to get them to work when they're defined up front...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I was given [this solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/zoqcGo?p=info) in the angular gitter by @brandonroberts.)

I had been under the impression that I could upgrade a component that was already in the angular 1 module on use, but it turns out that you need to fully upgrade the component before bootstrap.

The upgrade adapter must be run before bootstrap.

so

```
 directives: [adapter.upgradeNg1Component('testy')]
```

becomes

```
 directives: [ Testy ]
```

and Testy gets loaded/exported in upgraded form before bootstrap

```
import {adapter} from './adapter';
export default adapter.upgradeNg1Component('testy');
```

This does cast a bit of a pall on certain upgrade scenarios. I had been hoping to avoid having to load certain fat dependencies prior to bootstrap. At least I'll still be able to lazy load the rest of the routes' components, though.